# Is This a Binary Search Tree?

Tags: binary-search-tree, traversal, inorder

[image]
In the image Node value 4 if i change it to 0 will this be called a binary search tree??
If we do Inorder Traversal on this it will not show up in increasing order when 4 value is changed to 0